# Spring Boot WebFlux Not Working Request Controller

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-webflux

**I wrote a rest api using webflux and I used liquebase in this project, but when I sent the project calisdirib request at the end, I saw that the controller did not work. I can't find the problem.**

**What the problem ? When I query using locahost,
it doesn't come here (not working request)**

**Please help me**

**My Postman Error**

```
    org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 404 
NOT_FOUND\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.reactive.
  resource.ResourceWebHandler.lambda$handle$1(R 
  esourceWebHandler.java:378)\r\n\tSuppressed: 
 reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: \nError has 
been observed at the following site(s):\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET 
\"/api/label\" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]\nStack trace:\r\n\t\tat 
 org.springframework.web.reactive.resource.ResourceWebHandler.
 lambda$handle$1(R 
 esourceWebHandler.java:378)\r\n\t\tat 
 reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)\r\n\t\tat 
 reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)\r\n\t\tat
```

**My Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/label")//When I query using locahost, it doesn't come here (not working request)
public class LabelController {

 @Autowired
 LabelService labelService;//this service layer
 @GetMapping
 public Flux<LabelEntity> getAllLabels(){
     return labelService.getAll();
  }
 }
```

**Main Class**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableR2dbcRepositories
 @ComponentScan("com.WebFluxTestCodes.WebFluxTestCodes.business.*")
 public class WebFluxTestCodesApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebFluxTestCodesApplication.class, args);//main class 
  }

 }
```

**pom.xml**

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.WebFluxTestCodes</groupId>
<artifactId>WebFluxTestCodes</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>WebFluxTestCodes</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>//r2dbc reactive dependency 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>//jdbc 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>//liquibase database version control
        <version>3.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>//postgre database
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>//lombok library anotation getter setter and other
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: I believe we'll need a bit more context here. Please post controller and application classes (or relevant excerpts.)

Comment: Can you post your Controller, routes. How you defined the endpoints?

Comment: There is no request to labelcontroller

Comment: several things can be wrong, is your folder structure correct so that the RestController is being picked up and registered by the framework?

Comment: I didn't understand how so

Comment: If you're not sure what else to do, upload the complete non-working project to Github and link to it here.

Comment: Okey not problem

Comment: https://github.com/Z-Farrukzada/Webflux-Reactive-Programming-example

Comment: Michael Berry was able to look  my github?

Comment: Zaur, did you find a solution to your issue? I'm facing the exact same one.

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT**: The answer below is/was a temporary hack. Not the ideal solution since you loose non blocking features. Use a better alternative if you have.

I faced the same issue weeks ago. Got it fixed by changing the embedded container from netty to tomcat. Here's the fix for gradle :

```
\\ build.gradle

        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux") {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty'
    }
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

Comment: By switching form netty to tomcat you are loosing the non-blocking features provided by WebFlux. This solution is non or not "ideal" I'd say.

Comment: Agreed, @JimBob. Temporary hack,  it was - I may update the answer to say so. I still didn't find a proper way to tackle the root issue.